# FluentAssertions reference not importing properly

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, assembly-references, fluent-assertions

If I download FluentAssertions 1.7.1 (which all of my unit tests are currently written against) then I can do a reference to the dll and the test below will work just fine.

But I tried to upgrade via NuGet and using FluentAssertions versions 3.0.90 and also tried 3.0.107.  I tried to make a brand new solution/Class Library project after running into problems, but it can't detect anything from the library...

The test below won't compile because the `.Should` extension method can't be found for `bool`... or anything else for that matter. <strike>But I can clearly see it exists in the Object Browser</strike> I can see **FluentAssertions** and **FluentAssertions.Core** in my assembly references, but only view **FluentAssertions.Core** in the Object Browser. The only thing Intellisence seems to find for extension methods is `.ShouldRaisePropertyChangeFor<...>` and `.ShouldNotRaisePropertyChangeFor<...>`.

My project targets .Net4.0 and at this point I'm thinking it's a config problem, but I'm not sure where to start looking if it is.  No one else on Google seems to have this issue.

```cs
using System;
using FluentAssertions;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace IntegrationTests.CommonTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class _BasicTemplate_Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Run_Basic_Test()
        {
            true.Should().Be(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, looks like I can get V2.2.0 working...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because v3.0 requires [4.0.3 of the .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/03/05/update-4-0-3-for-the-microsoft-net-framework-4.aspx) framework (which most people are already using).